# Verify recursion formula

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, binomial-distribution

I have the following problem

When calculating all the values of a binomial distribution, the work can usually be simplified by first calculating $b(0;n,θ)$and then using the recursion formula

$b(x+1;n,θ)=\frac{θ(n−x)}{(x+1)(1−θ)}·b(x;n,θ)$

Verify this formula and use it to calculate the values of the binomial distribution with $n=7$ and $θ=0.25$

I have no clue where to begin or how to prove this. I'm looking for some help or at least a nudge in the right direction

Update: I figured out how to prove it, and I got 0.3115 as the answer? I think this is correct. Thoughts?

Comment: I'd guess mathematical induction. // Seems like a pre-computer age problem. In R, `round(dbinom(0:7, 7, .25),4)` returns **_eight_** probabilities 0.1335, 0.3115, 0.3115, 0.1730, 0.0577, 0.0115, 0.0013, 0.0001. [I rounded to 4 places so results would fit nicely in Comment format.]

Comment: Simply take the ratio $b(x+1;n,\theta)/b(x;n,\theta)$ and see what you get on simplification. And what answer are you looking for? You are given that $n=7,\theta=0.25$ and you are asked to 'calculate the values of the binomial distribution', which means listing the values of $b(x;7,0.25)$ for $x=0,1,\ldots,7$.